# CloudFormationのStackのParameterが、テンプレート内のデフォルト値を書き換えたにも関わらず更新されない

Tags: aws, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

ローカルでテンプレートファイルを管理しているLambdaのスタックを、 `aws cloudformation package` `aws cloudformation deloy` で更新しようとしました。  
実際にデプロイは成功し、スタックのテンプレートも更新されております。しかし、パラメータの値が変更されていないので不思議に思っています。

以下のような変更を加えました。

main.yml(変更前):

```
Parameters:
  MyKey:
    Type: String
    Default: ABC
```

main.yml(変更後):

```
Parameters:
  MyKey:
    Type: String
    Default: DEF
```

デプロイ後、コンソール画面から `Template` を確認すると、Defaultには更新後の `DEF` という値が表示されています。
しかし、スタックの `Parameter` を参照すると、更新前の `ABC` という値が表示されています。

スタックが更新されていること、ステータスが直近時刻の `UPDATE_COMPLETE` であることから、スタックの更新自体は行われたものと推測しています。であれば、スタックのパラメータが更新されない理由がわかりません。

どなたかお知恵をお貸しいただければ幸いです。

[環境]
aws cli: aws-cli/1.15.83 Python/3.6.5 Darwin/18.0.0 botocore/1.10.82
REGION: ap-northeast-1

Comment: 既に作成済みのスタックに対して、`Parameter`のデフォ値更新は適応されないそうです… https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51249700/cloudformation-wont-deploy-changes-when-default-param-is-changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

チラホラと述べられていますが、CloudFormation のテンプレートのデフォルトパラメータは、 Stack 作成時に、明示的に指定がない場合、その値でもって引数パラメータとして環境の初期化を行うための仕組みの様子です。

一度初期化した後には、デフォルトからコピーされた値が CloudFormation 上で管理されることになり、その値がデフォルト利用なのかユーザーが明示的に指定したものなのかの管理は、 CloudFormation では行われない様子です。

ですので、デフォルトパラメータを更新した際に、それを既存の Stack に適用するためには明示的に Stack のパラメータ更新を行う必要がある様子です。

参考: @maya2250 さんのリンク https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51249700/cloudformation-wont-deploy-changes-when-default-param-is-changed

Answer (score 0):

yml内に記述するparameter値はstackには反映されません。
stackをdeployするときにコマンドラインやコンソールから入力すれば、それが画面上では反映されます。